# Use main theme's CSS for the outer wrapper in list-category-posts?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

All the HTML and CSS shortcode handles are fantastic!  I'm able to simply reference my main theme's existing CSS to instantly format the content.  What I don't know how to do is formatting the overall list container.

How can reference the main theme's gallery CSS and apply a /div class=mygallerytheme/ wrapper around the list?  The div needs to sit just above the starting /ul/.  (That div also handles the responsive sizing, formatting, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

To format the overall list container use the class paramater:

> **class** - CSS class for the default UL generated by the plugin.

Also, you can change the generated code to a div if you pass the parameter "div" to "template":

```
[catlist  template=div class=mygallerytheme]
```

This will create something like:

```
<div class="mygallerytheme">
  <p>Post 1</p>
  <p>Post 2</p>
</div>
```

Other than that, to include a wrapper around the default ul, you should use the template system to wrap the [catlist] calls with a custom div.

Comment: Before I read this I tried out the TEMPLATE system and it worked beautifully!  I just added the theme-specific CCS and HTML calls.

I can post the code chunks here if anyone's curious (it's for the Trine WP theme).

Comment: So, did this answer the question? If so, mark it as correct. Otherwise, add your answer :)